# Which HTTP code to use for an empty subresource in a REST API?

Tags: rest, collections, semantics, http-status-codes

Let's say I've a resource `articles` at `/articles`.

These articles may have related articles, so I fetch them by GETting `/articles/{id}/related`.

What should I return is there is no related articles?

I can think of:

- `404 Not Found`, maybe with an empty collection
- `204 No Content`
- `200 Found` with an empty collection

Any advices? (please give arguments)

By the way, it may applies to pagination. If I request page 3 of 2, then the page 3 will return an empty set, should It be a `404`?

Answer (score 17):

`404` is not what you are looking for. It's an **error** condition. Your case is not an error. The client currently doesn't know if there are any related articles and wants to know. That is not an error.

`204` is not appropriate either. RFC 2616 states:

```
  The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an
  entity-body, and might want to return updated metainformation. The
  response MAY include new or updated metainformation in the form of
  entity-headers, which if present SHOULD be associated with the
  requested variant.
```

`204` doesn't specify that there are no related articles. It just says that the server doesn't need to send the data.

`200` with empty collection on the other hand would satisfy your need.

Comment: 200 is a good match but stay away from `200 Found` since _302 Found_ already exists.

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't use `404` -- that would tell the client it "I'm unable to tell you *whether* there are any releated articles".  It would be appropriate if the {id} given is not recognized at all. What you want is a positive response to tell the client, yes, good question, and here is the (empty) list of related articles.

`204` is not good either, for related reasons. It specified that *there is no answer*, which is still different from an answer that *is* there but happens to be the empty list. Its description makes more sense for a `POST` than for a `GET`.

`200` with an empty list is just right.

Answer (score 4):

Return 200 with an empty array.