# Response status code for searches in REST APIs

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes

Suppose, we have the following API:

```
GET /api/guests/{id}
```

```
GET /api/guests?name=dummy
```

Which status code should I return when there are no guests matching criteria? I mean no guests with name *dummy*.

Should it be `404`, `204` or `200` with an empty array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564031/which-http-code-to-use-for-an-empty-subresource-in-a-rest-api

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would return 200 with an empty array...
Or a 204 (No Content)

A 404 is when a *resource* isn't found.
Your resource in this case is the collection of guests... which exists.

Answer (score 25):

### The proper status code for each situation

Consider the following situations:

- `GET /api/guests?name=dummy`

It's an operation that requests a representation of a collection. If no items match the search criteria, return a [`200`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) status code with an empty array in the response body, indicating that the request was successfully received, understood, and accepted by the server, and collection itself exists but the search returned no results.

- `GET /api/guests/{id}`

It's an operation that requests representation of a single resource using its unique identifier. If no resource was found return a [`404`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4) error, indicating that the server did not find the resource with that identifier.

### More details

Have a look at the status code definitions in the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) (which updates the old [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616)). It's pretty clear:

> **[6.3.1. 200 OK](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1)**
>
> The `200` (OK) status code **indicates that the request has succeeded**. The payload sent in a 200 response depends on the request method. For the methods defined by this specification, the intended meaning of the payload can be summarized as:
>
> - `GET`: a representation of the target resource;
> - `HEAD`: the same representation as GET, but without the representation data;
> - `POST`: a representation of the status of, or results obtained from, the action;
> - `PUT`, `DELETE`: a representation of the status of the action;
> - `OPTIONS`: a representation of the communications options;
> - `TRACE`: a representation of the request message as received by the end server.
>
> [...]

> **[6.3.5. 204 No Content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5)**
>
> The `204` (No Content) status code **indicates that the server has successfully fulfilled the request and that there is no additional content to send in the response payload body**. Metadata in the response header fields refer to the target resource and its selected representation after the requested action was applied.
>
> [...]

> **[6.5.4. 404 Not Found](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4)**
>
> The `404` (Not Found) status code **indicates that the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists**.  A `404` status code does not indicate whether this lack of representation is temporary or permanent; the `410` (Gone) status code is preferred over `404` if the origin server knows, presumably through some configurable means, that the condition is likely to be permanent.
>
> [...]

The HTTP status codes are organized in classes. Have a look at this:

> **[6.3. Successful 2xx](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3)**
>
> The `2xx` (Successful) class of status code **indicates that the client's request was successfully received, understood, and accepted**.

> **[6.5.  Client Error 4xx](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5)**
>
> The `4xx` (Client Error) class of status code **indicates that the client seems to have erred**. Except when responding to a `HEAD` request, the server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition.
>
> [...]

Comment: 204 is nice didn't think on that!

Comment: I wouldn't use 204 - as a client, I'd want 200 and an array with 0/1/2/3... entries if you found 0/1/2/3... matching items. 204 only if the client doesn't really want any response other than "Ok, I've done it".

Comment: 2616 has been out of date for a while. Please use RFCs 7230-7235 instead.

Comment: Another: me too, 204 is nice!

Answer (score 4):

**200** and empty list of items. As the guest **ressource** in general **is found** but it has no matching items  for your query