# Shall restful response include or exclude empty result?

Tags: rest, response

Here is a api that use a batch of user id to get the users

**GET /user/{user_id}**

**user_id** : *comma separated string*

**e.g.** http://user.example.com/user/1,2,3

Now I have 2 users in id 1 and 2, but no user for id 3.

And shall the response include the empty user or exclude?

**Include example:**

`{
    "id":"1",
    "name":"Chris",
    "age":29
 },
 {
    "id":"2",
    "name":"Max",
    "age":30
 },
 {
    "id":"3"
 }`

**Exclude example:**

`{
    "id":"1",
    "name":"Chris",
    "age":29
 },
 {
    "id":"2",
    "name":"Max",
    "age":30
 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's no resource with the given identifier, it must not be included in the response.

---

If you have a collection of users, try to identify it with a *plural noun* (`/users` instead of `/user`) and use a query string parameter to filter it, such as `/users?ids=1,2,3`.

When using JSON to represent a collection, use an *array* (which begins with `[` and ends with `]` and separates the values with `,`).

---

For more details regarding the status codes that should be used when requesting a representation of a collection or a representation of a single resource, refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34945989/1426227).

Comment: Thank u Molin~ This is a useful answer~