# rest Http verb best practice for querying data

Tags: rest, api, http

I have read that it best practice to use method in REST as an indicator of operation performed on the resource.Lets say i have 5 operation,I am using below resource and methods:

```
Resource /customer- POST- CreateCustomer
DELETE-delete customer
PUT-update customer
```

Now I have 2 more operations  of query : `findCustomer` and `queryCustomer`.
I can use GET method for one of them only.What is the best practice to handle such scenario because passing an explicit HTTP header or extra query string for identifying 1 exceptional opertaion doesnt seem like a good alternative !

Comment: Whats the diff bet findCustomer and queryCustomer?

Comment: functionality is like in findCustomer input will be mobile/email wherein multiple customers could be returned and in queryCustomer input will be partyid which will respond details of specify customer id only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have 2 more operations of query: `findCustomer` and `queryCustomer`. I can use `GET` method for one of them only.

The `GET` method is suitable for both operations, however you must use different URIs.

Use the following to retrieve a representation of a collection of customers (the operation you define as *query*):

```
GET /customers
```

The collections can be filtered with *query parameters*.

And use the following to retrieve a representation of a single customer (the operation you define as *find*):

```
GET /customers/{id}
```

`{id}` is a unique identifier for your customer.

---

<sup>**Related:** See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34945989/1426227) for some insights on which status code can be returned in each situation.</sup>

Comment: if i use /customers/{id} then id will become the path(resource) parameter and will be applicable to all the HTTP verbs ,isnt it ?

Comment: @darshankamat It depends on your implementation. Most frameworks allow you to define which methods can be handled by a given endpoint.