# How to keep ResponseBody on 204 No Content response?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, httpresponse

I want to return a `204 no content` http status code. Though I want to add a custom error messages that gives details *why* where was no content.

Problem: I'm using `spring-mvc`, and when returning `HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT` type, the response body is always removed and empty for the client!

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExeptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public Object handler(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

If I change the type eg to `HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND` then the error message is shown as response body.

How can I achieve the same with 204?

Comment: you can set your value in cookie and read from cookie in client side.

Comment: 2xx status codes indicate success and thus should have no error message at all. The fact you want to respond with an "error" message or suggestion, means 4xx is probably a more valid response as those are client errors.

Answer (score 29):

> I want to return a `204` no content HTTP status code. Though I want to add a custom error messages that gives details why where was no content.

You can't.

> Problem: I'm using Spring MVC, and when returning `HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT` type, the response body is always removed and empty for the client!

That's the expected behaviour.

> If I change the type eg to `HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND` then the error message is shown as response body. How can I achieve the same with 204?

You won't achieve it with [`204`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5). You are misunderstanding (and probably misusing) such status code. The purpose of [`204`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5) is to indicate that **the server has successfully fulfilled the request and there's not additional content to send in the response payload**.

For reference, see how this status code is defined in the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231):

> [**6.3.5.  204 No Content**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5)
>
> The `204` (No Content) status code indicates that the server has
> successfully fulfilled the request and that there is no additional
> content to send in the response payload body. [...]
>
> A `204` response is terminated by the first empty line after the header
> fields because it cannot contain a message body. [...]

---

Depending on the situation, you'd better use [`404`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4) or [`200`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) with an empty array in the response payload. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34945989/1426227) may give you some insights.

Answer (score 3):

204 is for successful requests. It should have no error message included.

If an error happened, a different HTTP Code should be used.

see https://httpstatuses.com/204

**A 204 response is terminated by the first empty line after the header fields because it cannot contain a message body.**

Comment: If so, what would be the correct error message to show if "no content" could be found for a request, but the request itself was totally valid? Eg if I want to find a stocks product, which existed before but is not available anymore due to sold out etc?

Comment: @membersound  404 (pronounced "four oh four") error message is a Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) standard response code, in computer network communications, to indicate that the client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested.

Comment: Well but the same `404` is returned if eg the called servlet is not available. Eg if I call `localhost:8080/somestuff` which does not exist I get a 404. Then if I call `localhost.8080/producs/123` and the product could not be found, a `404` could indicate both that the `/producs` servlet is not available at all, or that the product could not be found. I'd like to differ that and keep 404 only for nonexisting servlet paths...

Comment: If the client shouldn't be asking for non-existent products, then 404 is the best-practice REST response. If there's a valid scenario in which it speculatively asks for matching products, then the best practice is to have a query URL which returns a *list* (e.g. in XML or JSON), so if there is no matching product the response is a 200 with an empty list as the body. In JSON `{ products = []}`