# Body not being displayed when response is 204

Tags: spring-boot, rest, kotlin, post

Locally when testing in postman I return my ID correctly but when I get to the case that I want to return a 204 status I return it but with no body message and can't seem to figure out why it's not displaying.

```
  @PostMapping("/ID_values/")
fun getID(
    @RequestBody
    email: String
): ResponseEntity<String> {
   return IDLookupService.lookupIDValue(email)
}  



    fun lookupIDValue(email: String): ResponseEntity<String> {
        val message = "processing the email failed please check input"
        logger.info(">>>processIDLookUpRequest")
        Failures.failsafeRun {
            IDRepo.findById(email)
        }
        val IDLookupResult = IDRepo.findById(email)
        logger.info("<<<processIDLookUpRequest")
        return if (IDResult.isPresent) {// this displays fine
            ResponseEntity(IDResult.get().optValue.toString(), HttpStatus.OK)

        } else {
            return ResponseEntity(message, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
               //the message here is not being displayed
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47410226/how-to-keep-responsebody-on-204-no-content-response

Answer (score 0):

Your message is not being displayed because you are returning a NO_CONTENT http request. Change your https status to OK and you Will get yout message.