# What is the correct HTTP status code for search results not found?

Tags: rest, http, spring-boot, httpresponse

We are implementing REST APIs in Java.

For GET REST endpoint, if I search for something:

1. If any records/record found, then it will return 200 status code and results/result.
2. If NO records found, what is the correct HTTP status code ?

When I searched in Google and SO, I found different answers like:

```
200 with empty list (if the API response is item but NOT list, then I can't send empty list)
204 No Content
404 Not Found
```

what is the correct HTTP status code if record not found or search results not found ?

Comment: You may consider using conventions of [github api](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/) or [youtube api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#response).

My opinion, i using 200 with empty list, same as above references.

Comment: If not finding anything is considered a client related error than return a 404, though in general this shouldn't be a failure per se IMO. `204 No Content` is more or less intended to inform a client that it can remain its current state as the processed request didn't change anythng. It is therefore more often used with `PUT` operations. Hence I'd go for `200 OK`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Response status code for searches in REST APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945736/response-status-code-for-searches-in-rest-apis)

Answer (score 12):

There are two different scenarios:

- For retrieving a representation of a *collection of resources* (for example, `GET /products?name=foo`) that has no items, return [`200`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) with an empty array.
- For retrieving a representation of a *single resource* (for example, `GET /products/1`) that doesn't exist, return [`404`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4).

The [`204`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5) status code is meant to be used, for example, as result of a `PUT` operation, allowing the server to indicate that the action has been successfully applied to the target resource. It doesn't fit for the scenarios described above.

---

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34945989/1426227) for further details.