# REST returns 404 for no records found but error keeps showing up in browser console

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, rxjs

I've a REST API that returns 404 when no records are found.

I'm using Rx and jQuery to call the API. I can catch the 404 response, but the error keeps showing up in the console of the browser as though the resource URL cannot be found when it actually is just because there were no records found.

How can I handle this sort of (no records found) 404 responses so that they don't show up in the console?

Or should "no records found" actually return 200 OK with an empty body?

Comment: Searching a bit looks like people tend to choose code 200 with empty response. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945736/response-status-code-for-searches-in-rest-apis http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564031/which-http-code-to-use-for-an-empty-subresource-in-a-rest-api

Comment: Why not HTTP 204 - No Content if you're going to send an empty response body.

Comment: yea I actually was just looking further into the different codes and realise that I could use 204. in this case, no content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was reading further into the different codes and figured that I could use 204 instead for "No Content".

404 would be if the resource itself is not found, not so much for the content of the response.

Answer (score 0):

**404** is the wrong status code.  Your server accepted the request, did what it had to do, and found no results.

**204** `No Content` would be a better response status code.